# cmake add_definitions and COMPILE_DEFINITIONS, how to see them

Tags: cmake

I want to see what the current set of compiler definitions is in my CMake file.  Ones automatically specified and the ones I'd added would be great. The `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS` macro doesn't appear to contain -- despite what the documentation says.

For example, in the below setup the message never includes `GUI_BUILD`

```
add_definitions( -DGUI_BUILD )
message( "COMPILE_DEFINITIONS = ${COMPILE_DEFINITIONS}" )
```

I don't need to see them in their final form, I just want a quick output to help verify that everything has been configured correctly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You want to extract the COMPILE_DEFINITIONS property from the [directory](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_dir:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS). E.g. use the following:

```
add_definitions( -DDebug )
get_directory_property( DirDefs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} COMPILE_DEFINITIONS )
```

Then you can simply iterate over them, e.g.:

```
foreach( d ${DirDefs} )
    message( STATUS "Found Define: " ${d} )
endforeach()
message( STATUS "DirDefs: " ${DirDefs} )
```

Note that definitions may also be associated with [targets](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS) or [source-files](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_sf:COMPILE_DEFINITIONS) instead of directories. And note that they can differ between configurations. Depending on your requirements, you may need to check a large set of different properties.

Comment: Thank you. Simply doing `get_directory_property( DirDefs COMPILE_DEFINITIONS )` and `message( "COMPILE_DEFINITIONS = ${DirDefs}" )` get me what I want.

Comment: Great to hear that it works. I was not really sure what you wanted to do with them, which is why I added the little list-printing and the notes about target and source-properties.

Comment: One other comment, in case you need it for debugging and you are using the gcc-compiler: cmake will generate a link.txt and flags.txt, holding the command-line options for the linker and compiler. You can check those as well.

Comment: That would be great. How can I generate those files?

Comment: Simply run cmake as usual and they will be generated for each library somewhere down in the CMakeFiles directory.

Comment: That may be true, but I can't find them. I did a `find -name "link*"` and nothing appeared. :(

Comment: @André how can copy DEFINE value, for example, when DirDefs contain's "val=value" copy value to a variable?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when using `target_compile_definitions`